# CSS layout changes with resolution

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm designing a chat page for a radio station and i am working on a 1360X768 Res' on a 32Inch screen.

When i ask friends to check the page layout it gets messy for them or elements get smaller in screen and the page wont stay consistent.

If its possible i would like to know if there is a fixed settings i need to insert to "body" in CSS so things like that wont happen, and when i move an element in my screen it will stay like that with other resolutions/screens.

[The web page in question](http://www.tranceil.fm/player/chat)

- Warning: There is music on Auto play in the page.

Also, if its ok to ask 2 different things but related.
I want to add the scrolling stats on the bottom to the bottom player..right where it says "now playing".

But everything i try wont make it go on top of it..z-index wont help.

Any thoughts?

Comment: User interface note: background music on a web page is _terrible_, especially with autoplay.

Comment: User interface note 2: fixed layout wider than 1000px _including margins_ is terrible. Not all users have 13xx screens. Those that don't will be forced to scroll horizontally (ter-ri-bleh)

Comment: Well..there is a player at the bottom with controls and it is a chat page for a radio station..;)

Comment: What if I want to chat about the radio station without listening to it (or searching for the player)

Comment: Thats the clients decision :)

Comment: @JanDvorak. On that width note, it's also increasingly difficult to read text that spans wider than maybe 600px (?).

Comment: @flem too bad the posts on Stack Exchange sites are 630px in width, slightly over the limit ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I get 660px in Chrome on this post. The 600px was a guesstimate. It's thereabouts :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The first mistake you're making is you're designing on a particular
  resolution.
- The second mistake you're making is that the resolution
  you're designing on is way above the most commonly used 1024x768.

Take a look at [MediaQueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). They allow you to build a fluid website that changes drastically at given resolutions.

Comment: So setting the width @ 100% instead of 1360..makes it global?

Comment: @TonalDev Setting the width 100% is a _great_ idea, but then you have to keep in mind that 100% on your screen is not 100% on my screen.

Comment: @TonalDev Check out [this simple demo](http://www.bitstampede.com/demos/media-queries/). It has a fluid width and when it gets really narrow, the menu moves and changes direction.

Comment: Thank you..checking that out as we speek! any thoughts on the scrolling stats?

Comment: @TonalDev. How about: `#statscontainer { position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; }`. It really depends on where you want it and where you've placed it. Play with `position: absolute` and `position: relative`.